# Why hasn't the minimum value of a+b been determined?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Why hasn't the minimum value of a+b been determined?

```
Minimize[{a + b, 9 == 9^(1/a) 3^(4/b), a b > 0}, {a, b}]
```

Find the minimum value of a+b. The limiting conditions are:

```
a b > 0

9 == 9^(1/a) 3^(4/b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

```
Minimize[{a + b, Reduce[9 == 9^(1/a) 3^(4/b) && a*b > 0, Reals]}, {a, b}]
```

> $\left\{2 \sqrt{2}+3,\left\{a\to \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{2}+4\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)^2-6 \left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)+1}}{\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{2}+4\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)^2-6 \left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)+1}-2},b\to \frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{2}+4\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)^2-6 \left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)+1}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: +1 Recommend that you add `// Simplify` to get a much cleaner form

Comment: @BobHanlon. Thank you for your valuable comment. `Simplify` performs `{3 + 2 Sqrt[2], {a -> 1 + Sqrt[2], b -> 2 + Sqrt[2]}}`.

Answer (score 1):

As the first condition is actually an equation, we may solve for b:

```
sol=Solve[9 == 9^(1/a) 3^(4/b), b][[1]]
```

[image]

As we want real numbers, we can delete the imaginary part by setting c1=0:

```
sol=sol /. C[1] -> 0
```

with this we can now minimize:

```
Minimize[{a + b, a  b > 0 } /. sol, a]
```

[[image]][2[image]

This gives `a== 1+ Sqrt[2]` and for b:

```
b /. sol /. a -> a -> 1 + Sqrt[2]
```

[image]